# How to adjust module order in typings.json

Tags: typescript

I am using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) to load type definitions. My project uses bluebird as promise implementation. Those two lines are in my `typings.json`:

```
"Promise": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts#dd328830dddffbe19e9addd7cf8532cbd3600816",
"node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts#48c1e3c1d6baefa4f1a126f188c27c4fefd36bff",
```

typings (version 1.0.3) generates the following `typings/index.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/Promise/index.d.ts" />
```

When compiling, tsc complains in all places where I used Promise, e.g. with:

```
error TS2339: Property 'exists' does not exist on type 'Promise<IResourcePatched> | Promise<string>'
```

However, the code is correct and worked before. Now I found out, that if I switch the order of the two lines in `typings/index.d.ts` to refer to bluebird first, my program compiles and works just like before...

Obviously tsc just takes the definition of Promise, which it sees first and the definition of Promise from node seems to differ slightly from the one from bluebird.

Question is: how to achieve, that typings lists the dependencies in `index.d.ts` in the order I need or how can I exclude the Promise declaration from the definition of node?

PS: Could someone with enough reputation add a tag for typings on StackOverflow?

**Update**: I just tried to change the order of the typings in `typings.json` but the node typings in index.d.ts always appear before Promise. They seem to be ordered alphabetically...

**Update 2**: It seems not to be a Promise definition in node, but one in the module "es6-shim", which is required as a dependency by angular2. So other names, same issue: the order.

**Note**: TypeScript-Compiler is configured to generate es5 code.

Answer (score 0):

The order isn't the issue here, the issue is that there are two conflicting definitions of `Promise`. Specifically the standard `Promise` definition used by TypeScript when you target `es6`/`es2015` doesn't match the one defined by `es6-shim`. Either configure TypeScript to target `es5`, or ditch `es6-shim`, the Angular2 quick-start appears to do the former.

Comment: That cannot be the reason, because in my tsconfig.json I configured it to generate for es5. You are right, there are two conflicting definitions, but they are in es6-shim and Bluebird, both included as external (formerly ambient) definitions. So there is still the question: How to handle that situation?

Comment: I cannot remove es6-shim, because I want to generate for es5 and I cannot remove Bluebird, as I want to use its additional Promise/A+ - Features (map, reduce, each, some, ...).

Comment: @user5876340 The es6-shim type definitions by their very nature must be ambient since the types they introduce are global. However the Bluebird type definitions come in two variants, the old ambient ones from DT (that you have installed) and the newer ones from NPM (that don't attempt to redefine `Promise`). Reinstall the type definitions for Bluebird from NPM and you should be able to work around these conflicts.

Comment: True, but this requires me to require Promise as bluebird from every module instead on relying, that it globally replaces Promise. Especially when mixing with other JS modules, which depend on returned promises being bluebird promises, this approach silently fails, when you forget to import Promise as bluebird in one module, because then a normal es6-promise is returned instead...

Answer (score 0):

What I found out seems to be valid for typings version 1.0.3 but might not be relieable in further versions, so handle with care.

The order of the reference paths in `typings/index.d.ts` seems to be based on the alphabetical order of the object key names in the `globalDependencies`- Object of `typings.json`. The name of the keys seems to serve no further purposes. So renaming the object keys such that the order fits your needs seems to be a working solution for the moment.

Typescript seems to keep the last definition of a global module (at least in version 1.8.10).

Big letters seem to be always sorted before small letters (A-Za-z), so alphabetical order probably means "order in ASCII table". I did not look at the source code to find out what it does exactly.